# Calculating alpha in EM / Baum-Welch algorithm for Hidden Markov

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization, baum-welch

I am trying to use this equation

[image]

to calculate the alpha (forward) probabilities for the EM/Baum-welch algorithm but I'm running into some confusion. I don't understand what the $h_t$ is. I know its a hidden state, I have 16 different hidden states but don't know which one is $h_1$ for instance. Can I arbitrarily assign them an index or are they related to $v_t$?

I current have a transition matrix, emission matrix and an initial vector as well as some series of observed emissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the source of the confusion is your notation.

Usually, one defines the forward variables $α_j(t)$ as the probability of the
partial observation sequence until time $t$, with state $S_j$ at time $t$ ([reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20170420132358/https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/rg/slides/hmm.pdf)).

Hence, under your notation, you use the forward procedure to calculate inductively $\alpha (h_t)$. If you have $T=16$ hidden states then you start at  $\alpha (h_1)$ and finish at $\alpha (h_{16})$;  each $\alpha (h_i)$ is a vector whose length is the number of total possible values the hidden states can take.

Comment: I think I understand what your saying, so $h_1$ is just the initial vector (the probabilities of starting in each hidden state)?

Comment: Yes, it's a vector of the same length as $\alpha (h_i)$. it's usually known as the prior;  supposed to reflect your  "belief" regarding the probability of a hidden state accepting a certain value,  before any evidence is taken into account.